# Allow one record from duplicated records into table with primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

I need your help with this request:

I have a view (`My_Class`) like this:

```
Name      Class     Color
----------------------------
Albert      A       Blue
John        B       Yellow
Albert      A       White
Gina        A       Grey
```

I want to insert this data into a SQL Server table (`Name_Class`) with this structure:

- Name Varchar(10)  Primary Key
- Class Varchar(2)

When running the following query:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Name_Class] (NAME, CLASS)
SELECT NAME, CLASS
FROM My_Class;
```

I got the following error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_NAME'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Name_Class'. The duplicate key value is (Albert)

**Question**: Is it possible to create a query to include only one Albert record (any) keeping `Name` as the primary key?

Table `Name_Class` (desired results):

```
Albert  A
John    B
Gina    C
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use GROUP BY, but you have always a problem, when Names are the not uinque

```
CREATE TABLE My_Class (
  [Name] VARCHAR(7),
  [Class] VARCHAR(4),
  [Color] VARCHAR(6)
);

INSERT INTO My_Class ([Name], [Class], [Color])
VALUES
  ('Albert', 'A', 'Blue'),
  ('John', 'B', 'Yellow'),
  ('Albert', 'A', 'White'),
  ('Gina', 'A', 'Grey');
GO
```

```
4 rows affected
```

```
SELECT [Name], [Class] FROM My_Class GROUP BY [Name], [Class]
GO
```

```
Name   | Class
:----- | :----
Albert | A    
Gina   | A    
John   | B
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5df6b9007c4f6a188b37b585dfeb7d8d)*

Answer (score 0):

Do you want aggregation?

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Name_Class] (NAME, CLASS)
SELECT NAME, MAX(CLASS)
FROM My_Class
GROUP BY NAME;
```

This guarantees one row per `name`, which complies with the primary key of the target table. If a name has multiple classes, the greatest class is retained.

Answer (score 0):

You could use DISTINCT.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Name_Class] (NAME, CLASS)
SELECT DISTINCT NAME, CLASS
FROM My_Class;
```